# Brew install CGAL and Eigen include files

Tags: c++, macos, homebrew, eigen, cgal

I have used Homebrew to install [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org) and its dependency solver package [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), and in that order

In my code I am trying to use the Eigen solver:

`typedef CGAL::Eigen_solver_traits<double> Solver;`

But, on building this code, I get this compilation time error:

```
  `/usr/local/Cellar/cgal/4.6.2/include/CGAL/Eigen_solver_traits.h:27:10: fatal error: 
  'Eigen/Sparse' file not found`
```

`Sparse.h` is located under `/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/`

I am not sure whether I should go and edit the code in CGAL's  `Eigen_solver_traits.h` to fix the path.

Also, the way Homebrew works confuses me, so I am not sure how to tell CGAL to find Eigen's include files.

Comment: How did you try and compile your code? Did you use cmake as recommended by CGAL?

Comment: I used the `cgal_create_cmake_script` in `/usr/local/bin` to generate a `CMakeLists.txt`. The make files generated from this CMake is the one I used for building my code. However, no where in the CMake script did I find a mention of Eigen.

Comment: Hmm, indeed, that script does not seem to handle Eigen :-( I think you need to add `find_package(Eigen3)` and `include( ${EIGEN3_USE_FILE} )` in your CMakeLists.txt, you can look for existing examples and demos that have similar code in their CMakeLists.txt (the goal is to get cmake to add `-I/usr/local/include/eigen3` to CXXFLAGS and thus to invocations of the compiler).

Comment: Thanks for your help. This indeed helped. If you would like to give an answer to this question, I am happy to upvote

Comment: I think it would be best if you posted a self-answer showing exactly what worked, this way we can be sure it actually solves your question ;-)